# About choosing a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I was browsing new questions when I saw [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155603/is-it-possible-to-transfer-schools-in-magical-world?noredirect=1&lq=1) already marked as a duplicate, since I happened to knew a possible answer I went to the [linked question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28039/are-there-canon-examples-of-students-permanently-transfering-from-one-school-to/155673#155673) and considered I could provide new content so I answered it.

After that I noticed that, in fact, the old question answers didn't really answer the new one which was actually more defined while the old question couldn't really be answered except partially. By answering the old question I effectively made the new question a duplicate (which in my opinion wasn't before since it asked something different that wasn't answered in the old question).

Now, I know the duplicate doesn't need to be the newer question and I actually like to favour new question, specially if they are better defined, so I voted to re-open it. Was it OK to do that? What should we do?

Sorry for the long story, hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few things going on here.

The question you've highlighted 
([Are magical exchange programmes possible in the Wizarding World?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155603/is-it-possible-to-transfer-schools-in-magical-world?noredirect=1&lq=1)) isn't actually a duplicate of the other question ([Are there canon examples of students permanently transfering from one school to another in Potterverse?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28039/are-there-canon-examples-of-students-permanently-transfering-from-one-school-to/155673#155673)) since one is asking about **permanent** transfers and the other is asking about **temporary** study programmes and exchanges.

It is, however a duplicate of an existing question ([Is there a such thing as an exchange program in Harry Potter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83009/is-there-a-such-thing-as-an-exchange-program-in-harry-potter)) which already has several canon answers.

---

I've used my gold badge to undupe the questions (which never should have been linked together) and re-duped the first question with the third.

You now need to copy [your answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/155673/20774) from the second question to the third since it adds new information about temporary transfers. You should also delete your answer from the second question since it doesn't actually answer the question asked (e.g. about permanent transfers).

---

For the record, you didn't make the second question a duplicate by answering since your answer ***didn't answer the question asked*** and would, I presume, have eventually been deleted by the community.

Comment: But the other questions didn't answer it either, my answer added a degree of plausibility

Comment: @Ram - Your answer is the answer to a different question. Regardless of the *plausibility* of your answer, it really shouldn't be there.